# Check for common items in other rows

Tags: r, dataframe, multiple-columns

I have more of a general question. I have a dataframe like below, consisting of ids that could have checked multiple items (at least 3, at max 6).

```
id  item_1      item_2      item_3      item_4      item_5      item_6
1   13103802    13060661    13339404    12896842    13308823    NA
2   448361      497992      13103802*   13002842    NA          NA
3   13031560    13103802*   13268709    2139908     1954965     12930979    
4   13060661*   13339404*   446881      13406902    NA          NA
5   12980231    12980231    12980231    NA          NA          NA
6   12896842*   13339404*   12717215    444032      13308823*   NA  
7   2098716     449342      13339070    12993196    2649922     NA  
8   2678151     12700906    12903744    2623298     12736032    349511  
9   2501765     2534504     2629353     NA          NA          NA  
10  12955428    12766447    12944593    NA          NA          NA
```

Now for each id I would like to count how many other ids share similar 1 to 6 items. So in the end I would like to add 6 more columns with counts of rows that share 1 item, 2 items etc..

So, based on data above, for the first row, column '1 item' would have value of 4, because it shares at least one item with rows 2,3,4 and 6, column '2 items' would have value of 2 because it shares at least 2 items with rows 4 and 6 and column '3 items' would have value of 1 because it shares at least 3 items with row 6, and so on (I marked values shared with first row in other rows with * so it is more visible I hope).

Not sure about the approach, can anyone help?

Comment: What do you mean by similar? items across ids do not seem equal

Comment: @Maël This is just top ten rows. If all the items are unique here, it is just a coincidence. There are similarities across the dataframe.

Comment: Then, it's better if you change your dataframe example to add identical items

Comment: @Maël I hope it is understandable in the way I have written it

Comment: Can you share an expected output? The new columns would have the same number for the column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bit messy and convoluted with `tidyverse`, but something you can try out. If this is close to what you need let me know.

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  pivot_longer(-id, names_pattern = "(\\d+)$") %>%
  filter(!is.na(value)) %>%
  mutate(n = n_distinct(id), ids = list(unique(id)), .by = value) %>%
  unnest(ids) %>%
  filter(id != ids) %>%
  reframe(freq = as.numeric(table(ids)), .by = id) %>%
  right_join(expand_grid(id = df$id, col = 1:(ncol(df)-1)), by = "id", multiple = "all") %>%
  replace_na(list(freq = 0)) %>%
  reframe(value = sum(freq >= col), .by = c("id", "col")) %>%
  pivot_wider(id_cols = id, names_from = col, values_from = value, names_prefix = "count") %>%
  arrange(id)
```

**Output**

```
      id count1 count2 count3 count4 count5 count6
   <int>  <int>  <int>  <int>  <int>  <int>  <int>
 1     1      4      2      1      0      0      0
 2     2      2      0      0      0      0      0
 3     3      2      0      0      0      0      0
 4     4      2      1      0      0      0      0
 5     5      0      0      0      0      0      0
 6     6      2      1      1      0      0      0
 7     7      0      0      0      0      0      0
 8     8      0      0      0      0      0      0
 9     9      0      0      0      0      0      0
10    10      0      0      0      0      0      0
```

**Data**

```
df <- structure(list(id = 1:10, item_1 = c(13103802L, 448361L, 13031560L, 
13060661L, 12980231L, 12896842L, 2098716L, 2678151L, 2501765L, 
12955428L), item_2 = c(13060661L, 497992L, 13103802L, 13339404L, 
12980231L, 13339404L, 449342L, 12700906L, 2534504L, 12766447L
), item_3 = c(13339404L, 13103802L, 13268709L, 446881L, 12980231L, 
12717215L, 13339070L, 12903744L, 2629353L, 12944593L), item_4 = c(12896842L, 
13002842L, 2139908L, 13406902L, NA, 444032L, 12993196L, 2623298L, 
NA, NA), item_5 = c(13308823L, NA, 1954965L, NA, NA, 13308823L, 
2649922L, 12736032L, NA, NA), item_6 = c(NA, NA, 12930979L, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, 349511L, NA, NA)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-10L))
```

Comment: Thanks! This looks exactly as what I need. I am just having trouble with reframe function. Is it from tidyverse package, right? I have reinstalled the whole package but it still throws an error `could not find function "reframe"`

Comment: @Pawels Check your dplyr version - should be 1.1.0 for that function…

Comment: Needed to upgrade R completely for that but it works now. Perfect, thanks a lot! Learned a lot about new dplyr functionalities.